# gettigng 404 error in the web api core with ef core

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

i want to post new record in web api core but im getting error.

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Savecity(string City)
        {
            using (var context = new jpdbContext())
            {
                Data1 data1 = new Data1();
                            data1.City = City;
                context.Data1.Add(data1);
                return Ok("Data saved successfully!!!");
            }

        }
```

https://localhost:44319/Data1/savecity?City=hyd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A 404 error indicates that the path you entered could not be found.

Please make sure that the Data1Controller where your Savecity method is located has a modified route.

Generally speaking, if it is an `api core` project, the controller will have default attribute **[Route("api/[controller]")]** , if you do not make any changes , then you should change your url to:

**https://localhost:44319/api/Data1?City=hyd**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class Data1Controller : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Savecity(string City)
        {
            using (var context = new jpdbContext())
            {
                Data1 data1 = new Data1();
                data1.City = City;
                context.Data1.Add(data1);
                return Ok("Data saved successfully!!!");
            }

        }
    }
```

If you want to display according to the url you entered, then you need to `modify the route to Savecity action`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DefaultController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("Savecity")]
    public ActionResult Savecity(string City)
    {
        using (var context = new jpdbContext())
        {
            Data1 data1 = new Data1();
            data1.City = City;
            context.Data1.Add(data1);
            return Ok("Data saved successfully!!!");
        }

    }
}
```

The url of this situation is :

**https://localhost:44319/api/Data1/Savecity?City=hyd**

More details, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1).